# Xamarin Insights for Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I was wondering how can we monitor the crashes using xamarin insights for Android.

In iOS if we just add

`Insights.Report(ex, Insights.Severity.Critical);` in the main fun of the main class if does the trick.

Where should I add this code in android so I could capture all the crashes in Android?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI Insights is being merged into HockeyApp. Thus you should use HockeyApp in the future: https://www.xamarin.com/faq#qha1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: Insight is deprecated

But, when we were using it, normally would set it up in main `Activity`'s `OnCreate`, something like:

```
protected override void OnCreate(global::Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
{
    Xamarin.Insights.Initialize(Keys.InsightsApiKey, this);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var ex = ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).GetBaseException();
            Console.WriteLine("**SPORT MAIN ACTIVITY EXCEPTION**\n\n" + ex);
            Insights.Report(ex, Xamarin.Insights.Severity.Critical);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    };
    ~~~~~~~
}
```

From the Xamarin Sport Example:

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Android/MainActivity.cs#L31

Comment: Do we need to initialize and report on each activity ??

Comment: In a `Xamarin.Forms` app you only usually have one `Activity`, i.e. `MainActivity`. You could also add it to a `Xamarin.Android` `Application` subclass in the `OnCreate` method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189393/how-to-perform-some-actions-before-letting-user-to-do-anything/39194677#39194677